# best way to handle backup API calls

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want get data from an API. This API has multiple URLs (for backup). Now I want to request URL1 first, if that returns data: Don't try the backup URLs. If URL doesn't return data, keep on trying. Here is what I have (and that seems to work as far as I can tell) but it looks really stupid:

```
const getData = async () => {
  let returnData = null;

  try {
    returnData = await axios.get(`${URL[0]}/${path}`);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(`Error fetching data: ${URL[0]}`, error);
  }

  if (!returnData) {
    try {
      returnData = await axios.get(`${URL[1]}/${path}`);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(`Error fetching data: ${URL[1]}`, error);
    }
  }

  if (!returnData) {
    try {
      returnData = await axios.get(`${URL[2]}/${path}`);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(`Error fetching data: ${URL[2]}`, error);
    }
  }

  if (!returnData) {
    try {
      returnData = await axios.get(`${URL[3]}/${path}`);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(`Error fetching data: ${URL[3]}`, error);
    }
  }

  if (!returnData) {
    try {
      returnData = await axios.get(`${URL[4]}/${path}`);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(`Error fetching data: ${URL[4]}`, error);
    }
  }

  if (!returnData) {
    try {
      returnData = await axios.get(`${URL[5]}/${path}`);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(`Error fetching data: ${URL[5]}`, error);
    }
  }

  if (!returnData) {
    try {
      returnData = await axios.get(`${URL[6]}/${path}`);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(`Error fetching data: ${URL[6]}`, error);
      throw new Error('last try fetching data:', error);
    }
  }

  return returnData;
}
```

What is the way to go here?

Comment: You can create an array with urls and loop through to fetch data, when it returns something stop execution

Comment: You can try to make a function and avoid the repetition and just call that. Also, You can do a loop on a array of URL part  (make a array of url if not present) and then try fetching them asynchron and waiting it the result is returned you just exit the loop without trying and use the value of it